# Can I select an element by its counter value?

Tags: css, css-counter

Is it possible to target an element based on its counter value? For example could I bold an element when my-counter is 10? So something like this:

```
body {
    //initialize the counter with a starting value of 5
    counter-reset: my-counter 5;
}

.some-class::before {
    // increment and insert the counter value in the element
    counter-increment: my-counter;
    content: counter(my-counter);
}

// is something like this possible?

.some-class::before::my-counter(10) {
    // target the element when its counter is 10
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For context, I'm doing this to make a responsive list (yes, 12 days of Christmas) where the same day is highlighted at all sizes.

[image: 12 Days of Christmas]

[image: 12 Days of Christmas cropped to 5 days]

[image: 12 Days of Christmas cropped to 3 days]

Comment: no but considering the fact that counter consider sibling element in most of the cases; you can maybe use nth-child() : `.some-class::nth-child(5)::before::` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use scripting, or, if the elements are next to eachother, `nth-child(x)`

```css
div.counted:nth-child(10){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="counted">1</div>
  <div class="counted">2</div>
  <div class="counted">3</div>
  <div class="counted">4</div>
  <div class="counted">5</div>
  <div class="counted">6</div>
  <div class="counted">7</div>
  <div class="counted">8</div>
  <div class="counted">9</div>
  <div class="counted">10</div>
  <div class="counted">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *//initialize the counter with a starting value of 5*

Comment: I was avoiding nth-child because I'm setting the starting value with an onresize event but want to target the same number regardless of how close it is to the start of the list. It sounds like I just need to handle this with JS.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div[data-count='1']{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-count="1">1</div>
  <div data-count="2">2</div>
  <div data-count="3">3</div>
  <div data-count="4">4</div>
  <div data-count="5">5</div>
</div>
```

You can avoid using `nth-child` if you modify the structure of your numbers by having another custom attribute like `data-count` with the desired value, which can be easily be selected using css.